# change color of cell based on difference between two dates

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, formatting, google-sheets-formula

I want to make it so that cell in column N changes to red if the date in column N cell 2 is more than 7 days past the date in the cell next to it in column  cell 2
so for example if column M, cell 2 (M2) is 10/1/23 and column N cell2 (N2) is 10/21/23 it would turn red.

Answer (score 0):

Try a conditional formating of your N2 cell with this formula :

`=DATEDIF(M2,N2,"D")>7`